# Converting int to currency with the use of selenium in c#

Tags: c#, selenium

Small question:

When I use sendkeys I fill in "100000". That field is automatically converting this to "€ 100.000". When I want to do an assert on my input and the value that is in the field. How can I fix this? I tried some things that I found on the forum but dont seem to fix this problem.

Comment: are you sending hardcode value 100000 or passing any other element gettext() output in it?

Comment: I send it hardcoded

Comment: that strange then. can you put that piece of code in your question which you are using for same

Comment: I added a picture. I think the field is modified by javascript.

Comment: of course .. the value you are sending is appending by your js. it is nothing to do with selenium

Comment: Ok. But how do I fix it so that I can do my assert correctly within selenium?

Comment: try with putting value manually in your application .. if it is still happening then it going to be verified

Comment: if your system is appending it then it's your use case to assert same as system should behave with € 100.000..

Comment: if you want your value to be check then getText it again and using split method extract your numerical value and then type cast it from string to int

Comment: I guess it could be your field validation issue. if you enter value as 30000 and it making manually as 30.000 then you have to enter value in that faishon

Comment: Did you try my solution/answer? As @ShubhamJain said, either you should assert for $10.000 (not the value you input), or you should just remove any unwanted characters (as proposed in my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what you are trying to do is to remove all non-digit characters from the string, after the js/jQuery has modified the input value by adding special characters to the original string (from 10000 to $10,000. In similar situations I usually use this helper function:

```
public static int GetAllDigitsFromString(string inputString) {
            return int.Parse(new String(inputString.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray()));
        }
```

If you use this, you could first get the string from the input field, then pass the value to this function, then use the return value of the function in your assert.

Since there is a discrepancy between the value you input (10000) and the value that is displayed ($10,000), maybe you should just account for this in your assert? If so, a more light-weight approach would be to just have your expected value set to "$10,000" in the test where you input 10000 to the field. Of course this depends on both test and solution design.

Answer (score -1):

If you're not familiar with it, you should read up about how to use "locale" in your coding.  I don't know C#, but found [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/syy068tk(v=vs.90).aspx) at MSDN with some sample code for translating a number to any localized currency.

The idea is that in your script you would pass your 100000 into the field under test, use getText to retrieve the text in the field, then compare that with the output of your own code that retrieves the localized currency for that same 100000 value.